# SQL: Wordpress users ordered by the date of their latest post (CPT)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

Need to get the last 5 users that posted in a certain **Custom Post Type (CTP)**. Since I seem not to be able to find a WordPress function to do so, I am trying to write a custom query.

So far I have gotten this in order to get the last five and their number of posts (for the my_custom_type only) but it is not working yet. 
Here is my query:

```
SELECT *, count(ID) 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'my_custom_type' 
GROUP BY post_author 
ORDER BY post_author DESC LIMIT 5
```

I would like to skip the admin (**post_author=1**).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order better by `ID` than `post_date` or `post_author` excluding admin `post_author>1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_author` != 1 
AND `post_status` = 'publish'
AND `post_type` = 'my_custom_type' 
GROUP BY `post_author` 
ORDER BY `ID` DESC, `post_author` ASC LIMIT 5
```

---

**Update:**

You will get now last 5 authors list ordered by ascendant date (ASC 'ID') that have 'published' posts (custom post type = 'my_custom_type'), excluding Admin (user ID = 1). And at the end the total post count for each author.

Here is the query:

```
select t1.*, t2.author_count
from `wp_posts` t1
inner join (
    select max(`ID`) as `ID`, `post_author`, count(1) as author_count
    from `wp_posts`
    where `post_author` != '1'
    and `post_status` = 'publish'
    and `post_type` = 'my_custom_type'
    group by `post_author`
) t2 on t1.`ID` = t2.`ID` and t1.`post_author` = t2.`post_author` 
order by t1.`ID` desc limit 5
```

`author_count` is the generated column that counts total `'published'` posts, with a `'post_type' = 'my_custom_type'` for each selected author.

Based on [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694535/3730754).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think it should be `ORDER BY 'post_date'`, right? in order to order it by the date of their latest post. It *kind of* work when not used with `GROUP BY 'post_author'` . if used with `GROUP BY 'post_author'`  it messes up the order. But if `GROUP BY 'post_author'` is not used, and a user happened to have posted twice recently, he will appear twice in the list results too. Please help!

Comment: it works like a charm if I dont use the `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT(ID)`. But then, as I mentioned, if a user happened to have posted twice recently, he will appear twice in the list results too. Also, I would like to get the user total posts if possible (with COUNT() or similar). Thank you for your help

Comment: I need to have the list of 5 users ordered by their last CTP posts. This is working without the `GROUP BY 'post_author' `. But if we don't use it , if a user happened to have posted twice recently, he will appear twice in the list results too. Also, I would like to get the user total posts if possible (with COUNT() or similar).

Comment: ok I can live without the counting total posts. But please then help with getting the 5 users ordered by their latest posts. PLEASE HELP! thanks

Comment: I wanted to get the user total posts, kind of killing 2 birds with one shot, but I can disregard that and use other functions to get that info per user later.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST and A LIFESAVER... THANK YOU!